# Keep getting StaleElement exception with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape Xero's app directory by using search terms and then crawling the results. I've tried putting in an implicit wait, catching the stale element exception in both the main and other functions, and slowing the script down to no avail. The issue appears to be in the pagecrawl code but don't why contents in apps object is always stale.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from random import randint 
from selenium.common import exceptions  


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5) #let DOM load
#load search URL
searchTerms = ["food and beverage","dentistry","auto dealerships","biotechnology","family office","clinic","laboratory","distribution","distributor","wholesale","calculate quotes","get funded","make payments","manage customers","manage human resources","manage projects","perform analytics","prepare taxes","receive payments","run payroll","send invoices","sync data","track expenses","track inventory","track time","agriculture","automotive","construction","education","franchise","health","hospitality","manufacturing","not for profit","professional services","realty","property","hospitality","retail","tourism","bills","CRM","Conversions","debtor","documents","e-commerce","financial services","inventory","invoicing","payments","payroll","HR","point of sale","practice management","reporting","consolidation","cashflow","investments"]
baseURL = "https://apps.xero.com/us/search?q="


#grab cards for each app in search term using class name

def main(searchTerms):
    with open('XeroScrapeout.csv','w',newline='') as f:
        try:
            #limited the search terms to a few I know will need page crawls
            for term in searchTerms[48:50]:
                #generate new list of apps and ratings for each page load based on search term
                apps= loadPage(baseURL,term)
                #write the apps from each page after it loads and specify which term is for each batch of apps
                appsScraped = writeApps(apps,term)
                writeApp(appsScraped,f)
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            print(e,term,"len(apps) is...",len(apps),"appsScraped...",appsScraped)
            pass
    f.close()
    driver.close()

def loadPage(baseURL,term):
    apps =[]
    #sleep(randint(10,30))
    url = baseURL+term
    driver.get(url)
    
    #allow following pages     
    pages2crawl = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("xui-button-medium")
    for page in pages2crawl:
        try:
            page2click = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
            page2click.click()
            sleep(2)
            apps.append(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mp-card__content"))
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            print(e,term,"x is...",x,"page2click is...",page2click.text,"\n","len apps is...",len(apps))
            pass
    #apps = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mp-card__content")
    return apps

#need to add code that grabs url of app
#writes text in m-card_content - app name, description, number of ratings
def writeApps(apps,term):
    appsScraped=[]
    for x in range(0,len(apps[0])):
        try:
            #code to write app.text to csv
            #adding again due to stale error
            import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
            apps = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mp-card__content")
            a=apps[0][x].text
            a = a.split('\n')
            line = term+";"+a[0]+";"+a[1]+";"+a[2]+";"+a[3]+";"
            appsScraped.append(line)
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            print(e)
            pass
    return appsScraped

def writeApp(appsScraped,f):
    if appsScraped:
        try:
            for x in range(0,len(appsScraped)):
                finalLine = appsScraped[x]+";"+'\n'
                f.write(finalLine)
        except:
            pass    
main(searchTerms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve ran into stale elements when there are new elements generated in the page such as pop ups or scrolling galleries as I am scraping. Try to make your scraping more focused with less room for errors of incorrect elements OR inspect the page and disable any elements not being used and see if it works then.

Stale Element = the element no longer exists.